# Lucene: How to select documents that has higher term overlap

Tags: lucene

I am using lucene to index and search documents. One criteria is to pick documents that have higher overlap with search term. Documents are small terms and are less than 10 words so.

example:

- doc1: "meaningful use case to be generated"
- doc2: "meaningful word use"

search: "meaningful use".

In this case, I would prefer doc2 to be ranked higher than doc1. I am using a bool query by making each of the terms a should clause. I am also setting min should match to 75%.

I would like to give the condition of scoring documents that have higher overlap with search and less unmatched terms to be scored higher.

Comment: Not sure exactly how you are setting the min should match to 75%, as there is no call in `BooleanQuery.Builder` to set that to a percentage. Regardless, what you are describing is the default behavior. How exactly do your results differ?

Comment: Yes, I understood that match is useless in this case. Didn't read the docs well. In my case the result chosen in of the longer phrase "meaningful use case to be generated". I also did some analysis and figured that bm25 scoring does include length but in my case that factor isn't enough to choose the smaller document. I also played around with  bm25 parameters and that didn't help either.